# How to manually program Int.Parse()

Tags: c#, java

We have this coding exercise to manually implement Int.Parse() method of .Net

I did not get how their 'correct' solution works. But I remember that it includes factoring the characters by tenth, hundredth...

I found a solution that is done with Java functions. Can someone explain to me how multiplying it by tens do the parsing of string to int?

```
public static int myStringToInteger(String str) {
    int answer = 0, factor = 1;
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        answer += (str.charAt(i) - '0') * factor;
        factor *= 10;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: take a paper and a pen, step by step try to see what it does.

Comment: Have you tried writing out a run? Say, on the input "235"?

Comment: Hint: 1234 = 4 + (3*10) + (2*10*10)+ (1*10*10*10)

Comment: @rik Beat me to it...

Comment: @david99world Probably because they should implement it themselves and find out that any number in any system can be represented as a polynomial.

Comment: I assumed that str is equal to a string and not integer. I get it if input is integer and I get confused what if the given string is actually a string like "hello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume it get's the following string: `"01234"`;

Answer is actually a sum of iterative values, starts from 0.
Factor is the multiplier you're multiplying nth digits.

It does this, essentially:

```
answer = 0

factor = 1
answer = answer + (4 * 1) = 0 + 4 = 4;

factor = 10;
answer = answer + (3 * 10) = 4 + 30 = 34;

factor = 100;
answer = answer + (2 * 100) = 34 + 200 = 234;

factor = 1000;
answer = answer + (1 * 1000) = 234 + 1000 = 1234;

factor = 1000;
answer = answer + (0 * 10000) = 1234 + 0 = 1234;
```

Of course, you need to take care of the case when the string consists of something more than ordinary digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the way using Linq,

```
  string st = "1234785";
  int i = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  st.All(x => {
  if (char.IsDigit(x))
   {
      i += (int)(char.GetNumericValue(x) * Math.Pow(10, (st.Length - counter - 1)));
   }
  counter++;
  return true;
});
```

after this, i = 1234785.

if you put some string like "hello" it will return 0 to you, if you pass string "Hello 123"
then it will return you 123.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not the place getting your home work done :-)

However, I remember, analyzing my fist programs in order to understand "how one does such things".
In later times I always used to refactor the foreign code into smaller pieces I could understand.

So, for the above snippet this could be:

```
public static int myStringToInteger(String str) {
    int answer = 0;
    int factor = 1;

    // Iterate over all characters (from right to left)
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // Determine the value of the current character
        // (I guess this is the trick you were missing
        // We extract a single character, subtract the 
        // ASCII value the character '0', getting the "distance"
        // from zero. So we converted a single character into
        // its integer value)
        char currentCharacter = str.charAt( i );
        int value = currentCharacter - '0';

        // Add the value of the character at the right place
        answer += value * factor;

        // Step one place further
        factor *= 10;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks though. It's not actually a homework, I just wanted to understand this one. Figured that I misunderstood the question.